Locator on table, how to get full html?
I got locators to tables from a frame.
Have two tables.

List<Locator> tables = f.locator("table").all();
for (Locator l: tables){
   .....
String r = l.getAttribute("id") + l.getAttribute("name");
                    System.out.println(r);
}

The display is nullnull when running in intellij debugger
Maybe there is a link with the fact that I cant get a direct locator with #tabPTR
This made me wonder how to get the full html
Surprisingly, When executed, I get the id displayed.
I am using v1.44
Upgraded version to 1.44
